# How to unwatch in Deno?

Tags: deno

There is a `Deno.watch` api to watch for file system events:

```
const watcher = Deno.watchFs("/");
for await (const event of watcher) {
   console.log(">>>> event", event);
   // { kind: "create", paths: [ "/foo.txt" ] }
}
```

But how to `unwatch` after `Deno.watch` called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call `watcher.return`

```
const watcher = Deno.watchFs("/your-dir");

setTimeout(() => {
  watcher.return();
}, 2000)

for await (const event of watcher) {
   console.log(">>>> event", event);
   // { kind: "create", paths: [ "/foo.txt" ] }
}
```

It's not recommended to watch the whole filesystem `/` it'll take a lot of time to start. `Deno.watchFs` call synchronously to `op_fs_events_open`. After a `watcher` is acquired operations are async.